# UISearchDisplayController's table view separator lines glitch when loading inside a modal view, how do I fix it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to load a basic search view overlaying my navigation controller (that is, *not* pushed on the navigation stack). To achieve this I'm using `[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO]`.

Full modal view presentation code:

```
- (void)searchButtonPressed
{
    TMSearchViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Search"];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
    vc.searchDisplayController.searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

After the modal view is presented on the screen, the following code—inside the search view's controller—is run:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:NO];
}
```

The problem is that when the search view renders, it does the normal thing where it blacks out the table view with a transparent black view, but it doesn't appear to cover the table view's separators, which looks like this:

[image: table view glitch]

I really have no idea how to fix it. My best guess is that it is something to do with the modal controller's process of loading a view that I'm not understanding properly. I've tried moving the `becomeFirstResponder` to the `viewDidLoad` method. I've also tried reordering the `setActive` method and the `becomeFirstResponder` method whilst changing the `setActive` method to `animated:NO` and `YES`.

So far, no avail, I'm clearly not understanding something here and I'm guessing I'm using something in a way that is unintended. Please help, Thanks :)

**edit**: interestingly enough, when I click the blacked out table view to `resignFirstResponder` the searchbar, and then click inside the searchbar again to activate `becomeFirstResponder` it loads fine, without the glitch, how it's meant to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after hours of messing around in the code, trying to understand what I'd done wrong, I've finally found the answer, or at least a fix. (I'm still mystified as to what was actually going wrong)

I simply deleted the searchbar from the interface builder in storyboard. And replaced it with another one—which involved reconnecting the searchbar to be the `searchDisplayController`'s searchbar property, of course.

My best guess is that Xcode for whatever reason didn't like the order in which I dragged in and connected the UI elements to interface builder/storyboard.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try     self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone; ??

Comment: No I actually didn't, only because I wanted separators, but I probably could have played around with when they were actually displayed. Good point.